# Gorm: Batch insert into ClickHouse with Array columns

Tags: go, clickhouse, go-gorm

I would like to batch-insert data into our ClickHouse database. Using `gorm`, I can easily use

```
type audit struct{
 field1 string `json:"field1"`,
 field2 string `json:"field2"`, 
}

chDB.Table(tableName).CreateInBatches(audits, 5)
```

However, if the `audit` contains an array field as below, the data of other fields will still be saved in the database. Only the field with array (`field1` as below) will not be saved.

```
type audit struct{
 field1 []string `json:"field1"`,
 field2 string   `json:"field2"`, 
}

chDB.Table(tableName).CreateInBatches(audits, 5)
```

Error:`[error] unsupported data type: &[]`

Only if I prepare a statement and save data then it works. However, in that case, it's not batch-insert anymore

```
sqlDB, err := db.DB()
tx, err := sqlDB.Begin()
stmt, err := tx.PrepareContext(ctx, `insert into audit_table (field1, field2) values (?, ?)`)
_, err = stmt.ExecContext(ctx, clickhouse.Array(audit.field1), audit.field2)
err = tx.Commit()
```

Can someone help me with this? How to batch-insert array-data into ClickHouse columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need `clickhouse.Array` Type to insert in `clickhouse.Array` column

```golang
type audit struct{
 field1 clickhouse.Array `json:"field1"`,
 field2 string           `json:"field2"`, 
}

audits := audit{
  field1: clickhouse.Array([]string{"one", "three"}),
  field2: "two"
}

chDB.Table(tableName).CreateInBatches(audits, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me, I needed to update my struct with the correct field tags, like so

```
type User struct {
    Timestamp    time.Time `gorm:"precision:6"`
    Name         string    `gorm:"type:LowCardinality(String)"`
    Age          int8
    DefaultValue string `gorm:"default:hello world"`
    Elapsed      time.Duration
    NullableInt  *int8    `gorm:"type:Nullable(Int8)"`
    Array        []string `gorm:"type:Array(String)"`
}
```

and could easily do batch inserts like so

```
    // Batch Insert
    user1 := User{Timestamp: time.Now(), Age: 12, Name: "Bruce Lee", Arraa: []string{"hello", "ne"}}
    user2 := User{Timestamp: time.Now(), Age: 13, Name: "Feynman", Arraa: []string{"no", "me"}}
    user3 := User{Timestamp: time.Now(), Age: 14, Name: "Angeliz"}
    var users = []User{user1, user2, user3}
    db.Create(&users)
```